# 'CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h' file not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmppframework

While integrating latest robbiehanson's XMPPFramework, I came up with an error :  `CocoaAsyncSocket/GCDAsyncSocket.h' file not found`

[image]

and a simliar kind of error:

`/Users/Con/Documents/PROJECTS/Cor/Cor/Libraries/XMPP Framework/Core/XMPPLogging.h:62:9: 'CocoaLumberJack/DDLog.h' file not found`

[image]

Help!

Answer (score 3):

open your `Built Setting` on your project, then set it like

```
User Header Search Paths = $(SRCROOT)   // recursive. 
Always Search User Paths = YES
```

Comment: What does that mean actually?

Comment: actaully your framework path not set into your directory

Comment: Please elaborate a bit. I don't want to be a copy-paste guy. :) Or this is it?